# How can I use SlideTransition(or the other animation) in ShellRoute at Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, animation, flutter-go-router

I'm using `ShellRoute` in `go_router` 13.0.0 and `BottomNavigationBar` to implements Nested Route.
However, I noticed that the transition animation is unnatural when the screen is routed.
So I tried to change routing animation in `ShellRoute`, but I can't.
I was also able to find someone who was experiencing similar problems to me.

[github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/139471)

And this is my code.

`routes.dart`

```
import 'package:baro_project/screens/calendar_screen.dart';
import 'package:baro_project/screens/info_screen.dart';
import 'package:baro_project/screens/youtube_screen.dart';
import 'package:baro_project/widgets/nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'screens/main_screen.dart';
import 'screens/noti_screen.dart';

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'Root');
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'Shell');

final router = GoRouter(navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey, initialLocation: '/login', routes: <RouteBase>[
  GoRoute(
    path: '/login',
    builder: (context, state) => const Login(),
  ),
  GoRoute(
    path: '/notification',
    builder: (context, state) => const NotificationManager(),
  ),
  ShellRoute(
    navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
    builder: (context, state, child) => NavBarWidget(child: child),
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/main',
        builder: (context, state) => const MainScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/calendar',
        builder: (context, state) => const CalendarScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/youtube',
        builder: (context, state) => const YoutubeScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/information',
        builder: (context, state) => const InformationScreen(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
]);
```

`nav_bar.dart`

```
import 'package:baro_project/widgets/app_bar.dart';
import 'package:baro_project/widgets/custom_drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class NavBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavBarWidget({super.key, required this.child});
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: customAppBar(context),
      body: child,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.house, size: 15.0),
            label: 'Main',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendar, size: 15.0),
            label: 'Calendar',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.youtube, size: 15.0),
            label: 'Youtube',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.user, size: 15.0),
            label: 'Information',
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (index) => _onItemTapped(index, context),
        currentIndex: _calculateIndex(context),
      ),
      endDrawer: customDrawer(context),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index, BuildContext context) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        GoRouter.of(context).go('/main');
        break;
      case 1:
        GoRouter.of(context).go('/calendar');
        break;
      case 2:
        GoRouter.of(context).go('/youtube');
        break;
      case 3:
        GoRouter.of(context).go('/information');
        break;
    }
  }

  int _calculateIndex(BuildContext context) {
    final currentLocation = GoRouterState.of(context).uri.toString();
    if (currentLocation == '/main') {
      return 0;
    }
    if (currentLocation == '/calendar') {
      return 1;
    }
    if (currentLocation == '/youtube') {
      return 2;
    }
    if (currentLocation == '/information') {
      return 3;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

I tried this way.

```
ShellRoute(
    navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
    builder: (context, state, child)  {
      var animation = ModalRoute.of(context)?.animation;
      if(animation == null) {
        return NavBarWidget(child: child);
      }
      return SlideTransition(
        position: Tween<Offset>(
          begin: const Offset(0, 1),
          end: Offset.zero,
        ).animate(animation),
        child: NavBarWidget(child: child),
      );
    },
```

In `BottomNavigationBar`, I wanted the animation moving to the right to be displayed when I clicked on the current item, and the animation moving to the left when I clicked on the left item.

No errors occurred in the code, but the animation did not change.

[my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwFtw.gif)

In addition, the basic routing animation of iOS emulators and Android emulators was being represented differently.
I'm using is an Android emulator.

What should I do?